# Is is possible to apply separate formatting to multiple different Excel table columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I have some calculated columns in an Excel (2007) table. I'd like to distinguish them visually from the user-input columns in some way, but without losing the nifty automatic row banding. It looks like I can create a "table style", but only the first and last columns can get separate formatting. Is there any way to format arbitrary columns (or at least the last *n* columns instead of just the last one)?

Answer (score 2):

You can format columns to unlock cells which are user-input, and then set conditional formatting for columns in your table specifying the formula condition =CELL("protect", ) as condition. Or you can set the following udf:

```
Function IsFormula(cell)
  IsFormula = cell.HasFormula
End Function
```

and then set an analogous conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't conditional formatting lose me the rest of the table formatting though? Specifically the row banding?

Comment: Yes, conditional formatting overwrites other formatting properties. It could not be different. You have to think a conditional formatting that is compatible with row banding. For example, a row banding with slight different colors than the other ones, or with different colors for text. About conditional formatting for row banding you can see http://www.google.com/search?q=row+banding+conditional+formatting+excel

Comment: Try to  set the color of cells in the columns using the conditional formatting. I tried it and you don't use the banding.